# Sharing a field method with class

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, extend, friend

I have a class with objects
Now i want to call a function from Box and Toy object from outside of the Container class

```
class Container
{
   Box box1 = new Box();
   Toy toy1 = new Toy();
   public void open()
   {
      box1.open();
   }
   public void play()
   {
      toy1.play();
   }
}
```

How can i avoid recreating the methods and just sharing the methods with the Container class.
I can not use inheritance because I have 2 or more objects.

Comment: Your way is as fine as it can be.

Comment: Sounds like composition is the way to go... just like you're doing it now.

Comment: Ok, since there is no better solution I will go with my original methods.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, the question now is posting an answer that it will not work also considered solving it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
public interface ToyInterface {
    public void play();
}

public class Toy implements ToyInterface {
    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Play toy");
    }
}

public interface BoxInterface {
    public void open();
}

public class Box implements BoxInterface {
    @Override
    public void open() {
        System.out.println("open box");
    }
}

public class Container implements ToyInterface, BoxInterface {
    private BoxInterface box;
    private ToyInterface toy;

    public Container() {
        box = new Box();
        toy = new Toy();
    }

    public BoxInterface getBox() {
        return box;
    }

    public ToyInterface getToy() {
        return toy;
    }

    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("play container");
        this.toy.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void open() {
        System.out.println("open container");
        this.box.open();
    }
}
```

Then you can access methods of Box and Toy class outside of the Container.

```
Container container = new Container();
container.open();
container.getBox().open();

container.play();
container.getToy().play();
```

Comment: Ok, sorry I should have said a "simple" solution :)

Comment: It looks complex but in brief it means that use interfaces when you need to use multiple inheritance.

Comment: It's not really what I had in mind to save me some work, but thanks anyway, this is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this :

<s>`main` or **where ever** you are *initializing* `Container` pass both **objects** to it</s>

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Box box1 = new Box();
   Toy toy1 = new Toy();
   Container c = new Container(box1, toy1);
   box1.open();
   toy1.play();
   //or pass both object where ever you want without recreating them
}

class Container {
    Box box1 = new Box();
    Toy toy1 = new Toy();   

    public Container(Box box1, Toy toy1){
        this.box1 = box1;
        this.toy1 = toy1;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :** Now as per your needs the following solution, but i also don't like doing this:

```
class Container
{
   public Box box1 = new Box(); // should not be public but as your needs
   public Toy toy1 = new Toy(); // should not be public but as your needs
}
container.box1.open();
container.toy1.play();
```

Comment: This misses the point of the question entirely. OP wants you to **delete the declarations of `open` and `play`** and for the solution to still work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik now is it OK.. ??

Comment: OP wants Container to have `open` and `play`, but without explicitly declaring them. He wants to automagically expose those methods from the contained objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i don't think so its possible without even creating a single method within container, is it ??, i have one solution, i think you wont like it ..

Comment: Yes, the point is you should delete the answer. This solution was already posted by amandino and the OP clearly said he is not looking for that.